# Overlaying text on top of an object

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a youtube video on my website. I would like to know if there is any way to lay out text on top of the video to give it a specific title.

Also how would I do the same but on the left side of the video? I am using bootstrap as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use z-index or position in-order to do this.

```
<div class="container">

<iframe width="560" height="315" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/YXVoqJEwqoQ" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    <div class="my-text"> This is my text</div>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
body {
    background: #efefea
}

.container {
    width: 600px; 
    margin: 0 auto; 
    padding: 10px;
    position: relative; 
}

iframe {
    marign: 0 auto; 
}

.my-text {
    position: absolute;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 10px 0px;
    text-align: center; 
    font-size: 50px; 
    background: rgba(0,0,0, 0.5);
    top: 20px;
    left: 0; 
    right: 0;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/websiddu/dy4exbcp/1/